# center two elements in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.blogmaster {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container1 {
 display: grid;
 gap: 100px;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img{
 width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border: 5px solid #555;
}
.square1 .square-image1 img{
 width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border: 5px solid #555;
}
.square .square-details{
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}
.square1 .square-details1{
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}
.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .parent-div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square{
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square .square-image img{
  height: 230px !important;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}
}
.square1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square1{
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 54px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square1 .square-image1 img{
  height: 230px !important;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}
}
```

```html
 <section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
        <div class="containerE">

  <div class="row1">
            <div class="container1">
              <div class="square">
                <div class="square-image">
                <img src="assets/img/Blog1.png">
                </div>

                <div class="square-details">
                  <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
                <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
              <div class="square1">
              <div class="square-image1">
              <img src="assets/img/Blog2.png">
                </div>

                <div class="square-details1">
                  <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
                <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
</section>
```

The problem I am facing is relating to the margin. So when you run the above code, open it on a new page, and then zoom out to `50%` or less, then you can see the output to be like this:

[image]

See how the left blog card is moved all the way to the left? It is some sort of a margin issue and I want to fix that.

### Expected Output

[image]

So I would like the alignment to be like the expected output picture I sent. Is there a way to set the `width: 100%` and have the blog cards alignment to be like in the expected output above? Because I do not want the width to be in `px` as when you zoom into `100%` on the page, then half of the blog card is cut off like it's no according to page width.

Any suggestions?

### Update

[image]

The alignment is still not like the expected output I sent. In the expected output, you can see that the first corner of the first blog card matches the first corner of the first bottom element, and the second corner of the second blog card matches the second corner of the second bottom element. Refer to the expected output, and it will make sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.blogmaster {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container1 {
 display: grid;
 gap: 100px;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img{
 width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border: 5px solid #555;
}
.square1 .square-image1 img{
 width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border: 5px solid #555;
}
.square .square-details{
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}
.square1 .square-details1{
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}
.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .parent-div {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square{
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square .square-image img{
  height: 230px !important;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}
}
.square1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-width: 460px;
  height: 100% !important;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square1{
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 54px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.square1 .square-image1 img{
  height: 230px !important;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}
}
```

```html
 <section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
        <div class="containerE">

  <div class="row1">
            <div class="container1">
              <div class="square">
                <div class="square-image">
                <img src="assets/img/Blog1.png">
                </div>

                <div class="square-details">
                  <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
                <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
              <div class="square1">
              <div class="square-image1">
              <img src="assets/img/Blog2.png">
                </div>

                <div class="square-details1">
                  <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
                <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
                  <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
</section>
```

use the above CSS, add margin-left: auto in square and margin-right: auto in square1, it will work